# I can't boot from USB: Error setting up gfxboot

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, ubuntu-netbook, toshiba

I have a Toshiba NB305 netbook, so if I want to install **Ubuntu** I have to do it by an USB.
I downloaded the ISO from the official webside and burned it to the USB, and when I try to install the system I get an error in a black window:

```
graphics initialization failled
Error setting up gfxboot
boot:  _
```

And the window doesn't move from there.

I've tried with **other versions**, but the result is the same.

What's the **problem** and how I can **solve** it?

Comment: Read this answer carefully: http://askubuntu.com/a/162076/95393

Answer (score 14):

Just type `help` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It will continue to boot normally.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/659253

Comment: Tested solving the problem OK on Lubuntu v16.04 LTS 32 bits.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The screen goes blank for a second, and then I return to the same screen. After a few tries, I then see `Could not allocate memory` when I try to run the command.

Comment: Update: While this didn't work for me on an Ubuntu 16.04LTS image, it _did_ work on Ubuntu 17.10. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try typing 'live' and hitting Enter. It worked for me just now!

Last week I was trying MX Linux 18.2 on my Samsung Chromebook 3. That distro presents a boot menu. "live" is the option that you have to choose to boot the USB image.
However, I love Ubuntu and my Samsung Chromebook 3.
So, I've so I've been trying to run Ubuntu on my chromebook for several years and always been presented with the dreaded message in this discussion. And, typing 'help'  didn't help me in the past.
So I hope this can help someone else.

I'm now running Xubuntu on my Samsung Chromebook 3. Good times!

Answer (score 1):

See this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1348978/861412.

*can't comment due to less reputation, so added the link to my answer.*