# Error setting up gfxboot

Tags: boot, system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 in a Toshiba NB255 that is currently running Windows 7.

When I boot from USB  I get the message

```
graphics initialization failed
Error setting up gfxboot
```

which appears over and over again, and then after a while a it says

```
could not allocate memory
```

I have tried the "help" solution and it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Such error occurred to me when installing ubuntu on Intel® Desktop Board DH67BL. What appeared to be a problem was that I was using VGA monitor on DVI port (using adapter from DVI to VGA).

When Installing Ubuntu Server 18.04 it actually helped typing "help" and hitting enter. Then installation menu appeared. However for Ubuntu Server 16.04 this didn't helped. So I changed to monitor with DVI interface using just DVI cable and this problem gone. Eventually I could install 16.04 successfully.

Hope it helps for someone.

Answer (score 2):

Getting the same messages as OP.

I typed in `help` and pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Got some kind of boot menu. While reading all the options, it self-launched into the proper installer as described on Ubuntu install pages.

So, recommend just waiting a minute or two after you get the boot menu.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but you have to press the Escape key and use the arrow keys and press the Enter key when the 'Advanced Options' are available so you can try to boot up from the USB drive to go into failsafe mode. It disables the

> Graphics Initialization Failed 
>   Error setting up gfxboot

(gfxboot = graphics boot) which allows you to troubleshoot your OS. I have the same problem too. I hope my answer helps! :D

Answer (score 0):

I tried for 5+ hrs. The above solutions of help + enter didn't work for me. I was repeatedly removing iso and re-linking but was still facing the same issue.

The mistake I was making to not allocate enough RAM while creating the VM. I'm running Virtual box on windows 10 pro and have installed Ubuntu 18.04.4 on it. I was allocating RAM in MB, to be accurate 10 MB, make sure you are allocating enough RAM to load the gfx. so you have to put values like 2048(2GB), 4096(4GB), and larger values for bigger RAM in the box(when it asks) to be able to get sufficient RAM(in GB) for the VM.